# Validating sudoku columns and rows

Tags: c++, sudoku

I'm writing a sudoku col/row validator, what is does is:

1. Reads user input on how many Sudoku instances to validate.
2. Reads the sudoku matrix grid 9x9 (for me, in my specific case 9x9) into a 2d array. Each line read/row should contain something like: `8 2 1 3 6 4 9 7 5`.
3. Validates each row and column by flipping a 9 bit bitset to test whether all columns and rows contains nums from 1-9.

Please note that the only purpose of this program is to validate sudoku columns/rows as specified and not to completely validate it. i.e also checking each sudoku block.

How can I improve my code? I believe there's lots to it, naming conventions, fundamental approach...etc..etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>

namespace Constants
{
    constexpr int ROW_COL_SIZE = 9;
    const std::string STR_YES = "YES";
    const std::string STR_NO = "NO";
}

template<unsigned int N>
class Sudoku
{
private:
    int m_matrix[N][N] {{0}};
public:
    void ReadRows();
    std::string strIsValid() const;
};

template<unsigned int N>void Sudoku<N>::ReadRows()
{
    for(unsigned int row{0}; row<N; row++)
    {
        static std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::istringstream issline(line);
        int readnum {0};
        for(unsigned int i{0}; i<N; i++)
        {
            issline >> readnum;
            m_matrix[row][i] = readnum;
        }
    }
}

template<unsigned int N>std::string Sudoku<N>::strIsValid() const
{
    //9bit default ctor all zeroes, 000000000
    std::bitset<N> bitRow[N];
    std::bitset<N> bitCol[N];
    for(int i{0}; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(int j{0}; j<N; j++)
        {
            bitRow[i].flip(m_matrix[i][j]-1); //verify nums 1-9 row, bitset index is 0 not 1.
            bitCol[i].flip(m_matrix[j][i]-1); //verify nums 1-9 col
        }
        if(!bitRow[i].all() && !bitCol[i].all())
        {
            return Constants::STR_NO;
        }
    }
    return Constants::STR_YES;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    int instances {0};
    std::cin >> instances;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();

    for(int i{0}; i<instances; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Instance " << i+1 << std::endl;
        Sudoku<Constants::ROW_COL_SIZE> sudokuInstance;
        sudokuInstance.ReadRows();
        std::cout << sudokuInstance.strIsValid() << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>*It is not a complete answer. Just some of my thoughts about this code.*</sub>

### C++

- **Do not compare integers of different signedness**. Loop counters `i` and `j` in function `strIsValid` are declared as `int`, but they are compared with `N` which is `unsigned int`. It could lead to some problems. Make the counters `unsigned`.
- **Use strict compilation flags**. The compiler would tell you about your signed/unsigned issue if you pass it `-Wall` key.

  You should always achieve that the compiler will not display any diagnostic messages with the most strict compilation keys (`-Wall`, `-Wextra`, `-pedantic`, etc).

  <sub>But you probably would [not want](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/06/dont-use-weverything/) to use Clang's `-Weverything`.</sub>
- **What happened with your `main`?** Your `main` function looks very unnatural:

  > ```
  > int main(int, char**)
  > ```

  If you do not need `argc` and `argv`, write just

  ```
  int main()
  ```
- **About `std::endl`**. You should avoid globally using `std::endl`. It is not the same as just `\n`. There is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14395960/8086115) on SO about this topic.

  And why are you printing `std::endl` twice?

  > ```
  > std::cout << sudokuInstance.strIsValid() << std::endl << std::endl;
  > ```
- **You do not have to explicitly return from `main`**. You [don't have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) to explicitly `return 0;` at the end of main.

### Programming

- **Minimize the scope of local variables**. You should always minimize the scope of local variables. In your case, for example, scope of the `readnum` variable can be reduced. Some [reading](https://refactoring.com/catalog/reduceScopeOfVariable.html) about this topic.
- **The predicative function should return boolean**. Your `strIsValid` is a *predicative function*. It means that this function checks something and returns either true or false. But you return *string* `"YES"` (true) or `"NO"` (false). You should return `bool` instead.
- **What the `strIsValid` function does?** The name of this function doesn't answer the question.

### Architecture

- **Validate user's input**. At this time you do not validate user's input in `ReadRows`. What if I'll input a number which is greater than 9? Or less than 0? If I'll input too many numbers?..

  In this case, you store invalid data into `m_matrix`. Then this invalid data will be used as arguments of `std::bitset`'s `flip()` which will cause `std::out_of_range`.
- **Split row and cols validating and reading user's input**. The `Sudoku` class should know nothing about reading user's input. The only thing that it should do is validate Sudoku columns and rows! This is called the Single Responsibility Principle ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Comment: Some of your thoughts about the code makes a valid code review, don't worry about that

Comment: I totally agree regarding "You should return `bool` instead".

Comment: tyvm, applied all I've learned,

Answer (score 3):

First, I just want to remark that this is excellent use of `std::bitset<>`!
Further, I'm just adding to eanmos's comments.

## Don't define constants that are named after their value

Apart from the fact that, as already mentioned, `strIsValid()` should return a `bool`, you define the constants `Constants::STR_YES` and `Constants::STR_NO`. These constants are longer to type than literal `"YES"` and `"NO"`. Also, consider that you would ever change the value of `STR_YES`. The code was written with the assumption that the constant would be the literal `"YES"`, as that is what its name clearly says, but now you are breaking that assumption. So in `main()`, just I would just write:

```
std::cout << sudokuInstance.strIsValid() ? "YES\n" : "NO\n";
```

If the goal is to make it easy to translate the program, then you should use a so-called internationalization library to do this, such as [gettext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext). Writing constants like this doesn't scale for programs with a large amount of text.

## Consider returning a meaningful value from `main()`

Your program prints whether each Sudoku instance is valid to standard output, but the exit code is always 0. It is custom to have the exit code be non-zero if an error happened. While technically your program still runs perfectly fine if you feed it an invalid Sudoku, you might consider returning 1 if it has encountered any non-valid Sudoku. This is similar to what some command line tools do, like `cmp` or `grep -q`.
This way, you can call your program from a shell script, and have the shell script react to the result of your program in an easy way, making it easy to integrate it into larger projects.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, tyvm